# SVG Folding Envelope

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I am toying with SVGs and how it works. I am trying to animate this SVG, where the envelope closes and flies off to the right, then a check mark appears.

So far, i have done the envelope SVG, i have managed to get the top to flip down, but it is above the envelope, i need it to close the envelope. It is also flipping in the wrong direction..

How do i fix this?

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 805 314" style="enable-background:new 0 0 805 314;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#3B97D3;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st1{fill:#F1F2F2;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st2{fill:#E6E7E8;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{
  transform-origin:55% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin:55% 50%;
  animation: flipX 1.6s forwards;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes flipX {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes flipX {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
  }
}
.flipX{
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation: flipX 2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) forwards;
 animation: flipX 2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) forwards;
}
</style>
<g id="Layer_1">
 <rect id="XMLID_42_" class="st0" width="805" height="314"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
 <rect id="XMLID_1_" x="55" y="129" class="st1" width="192" height="98"/>
 <g id="Layer_3">
  <polyline id="XMLID_43_" class="st2" points="55,129 151,178 247,129   "/>
  <polyline id="XMLID_3_" class="st3" points="55,129 151,64 247,129   "/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want something to move during a rotation, put it at the origin.

A quick fix in this case is to change the coordinates of the flap element so that the long edge has a y-coordinate of zero, then wrap the element in a `<g>` element with a transform attribute to place it where it's supposed to go.

Get rid of the `transform-origin` style too.

This works, but could be cleaned up a lot:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 805 314" style="enable-background:new 0 0 805 314;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#3B97D3;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st1{fill:#F1F2F2;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st2{fill:#E6E7E8;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{
  animation: flipX 1.6s forwards;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes flipX {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes flipX {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
  }
}
.flipX{
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation: flipX 2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) forwards;
 animation: flipX 2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) forwards;
}
</style>
<g>
 <rect class="st0" width="805" height="314"/>
</g>
<g>
 <rect x="55" y="129" class="st1" width="192" height="98"/>
 <g>
  <polyline class="st2" points="55,129 151,178 247,129 "/>
  <g transform="translate(0 129)">
   <polyline class="st3" points="55,0 151,-65 247,0 "/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That is perfect, just what i was after. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add `translateY(-65px)` to the `100%` keyframe, it moves the envelope flap down as it's flipping it. `65px` is an eyeball figure.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 805 314" style="enable-background:new 0 0 805 314;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#3B97D3;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st1{fill:#F1F2F2;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st2{fill:#E6E7E8;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{
  transform-origin:55% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin:55% 50%;
  animation: flipX 1.6s forwards;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes flipX {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1)  translateY(-65px);
  }
}
@keyframes flipX {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
    transform: perspective(400px) translateZ(0) rotateX(180deg) scale(1)  translateY(-65px);
  }
}
.flipX{
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-animation: flipX 2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) forwards;
 animation: flipX 2s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.9) forwards;
}
</style>
<g id="Layer_1">
 <rect id="XMLID_42_" class="st0" width="805" height="314"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
 <rect id="XMLID_1_" x="55" y="129" class="st1" width="192" height="98"/>

 <g id="Layer_3">
  <polyline id="XMLID_43_" class="st2" points="55,129 151,178 247,129   "/>
  <polyline id="XMLID_3_" class="st3" points="55,129 151,64 247,129   "/>
 </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to keep the bottom of that triangle fixed to the envelope as its in transition?